# table sorter pagination doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, tablesorter

I try to repeate actions from following article:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-tablesorter--cms-22095

Now I have following code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tablesorter Demo - Jeff Reifman</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/__jquery.tablesorter/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value='/resources/js/__jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.min.js'/>"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/blue/style.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Tablesorter Demo</h1>
<p><a href="./index.html">Home</a> | <a href="./pager.html">Pager</a> | <a href="./ajax.html">Ajax</a> | <a href="https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-tablesorter--cms-22095">Back to Tuts</a> | <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=reifman">Follow @reifman</a></p>
<p>Sortable table of domains for sale.</p>
<table id="domainsTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Domain name</th>
        <th>gTld</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td><a href="http://geogram.co">geogram.co</a></td><td>co</td><td>Internet</td><td>$49</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: geogram.co">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://newscloud.com">newscloud.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>News</td><td>$19999</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: newscloud.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://popcloud.com">popcloud.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Music</td><td>$14999</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: popcloud.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://geogram.com">geogram.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$1999</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: geogram.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://handwave.com">handwave.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$3499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: handwave.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://newsclouds.com">newsclouds.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>News</td><td>$2999</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: newsclouds.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://publishingwithwordpress.com">publishingwithwordpress.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$4999</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: publishingwithwordpress.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://teamgirl.com">teamgirl.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Shopping</td><td>$1999</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: teamgirl.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://customlife.com">customlife.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$1499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: customlife.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://givingspace.com">givingspace.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$1499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: givingspace.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://lifestick.com">lifestick.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$1499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: lifestick.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://mainstory.com">mainstory.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>News</td><td>$1299</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: mainstory.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://connectedyogi.com">connectedyogi.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Yoga</td><td>$999</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: connectedyogi.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://completeswift.com">completeswift.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Technology</td><td>$499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: completeswift.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://gettingstartedwithswift.com">gettingstartedwithswift.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Programming</td><td>$499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: gettingstartedwithswift.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://professionalswift.com">professionalswift.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Programming</td><td>$499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: professionalswift.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://ultimateswift.com">ultimateswift.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Programming</td><td>$499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: ultimateswift.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://surfarea.com">surfarea.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Sports</td><td>$699</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: surfarea.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://carestrategies.com">carestrategies.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Healthcare</td><td>$599</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: carestrategies.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://commontunes.com">commontunes.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Music</td><td>$499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: commontunes.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://filecross.com">filecross.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: filecross.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://filesquare.com">filesquare.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: filesquare.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>        
    <tr><td><a href="http://uwlink.com">uwlink.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Social</td><td>$299</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: uwlink.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://commonblogs.com">commonblogs.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Technology</td><td>$149</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: commonblogs.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://commonsites.com">commonsites.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$149</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: commonsites.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://efltr.com">efltr.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Technology</td><td>$249</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: efltr.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://emailthewhitehouse.com">emailthewhitehouse.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Politics</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: emailthewhitehouse.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://hong2.com">hong2.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Misc</td><td>$249</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: hong2.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    
    <tr><td><a href="http://jetcitynews.com">jetcitynews.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>News</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: jetcitynews.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://listshield.com">listshield.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: listshield.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://mailfilterapp.com">mailfilterapp.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: mailfilterapp.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://mysticspa.com">mysticspa.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Healthcare</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: mysticspa.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://oxygengirl.com">oxygengirl.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Shopping</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: oxygengirl.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://thecompletemac.com">thecompletemac.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Shopping</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: thecompletemac.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://parkingnotes.com">parkingnotes.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$79</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: parkingnotes.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://fifteenideas.com">fifteenideas.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Misc</td><td>$69</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: fifteenideas.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://geoletters.com">geoletters.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$69</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: geoletters.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://identitycircle.com">identitycircle.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$69</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: identitycircle.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://readyfilm.com">readyfilm.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Shopping</td><td>$69</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: readyfilm.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://stampfree.com">stampfree.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Shopping</td><td>$69</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: stampfree.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://tpmemo.com">tpmemo.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Misc</td><td>$69</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: tpmemo.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://geomailapp.com">geomailapp.com</a></td><td>com</td><td>Internet</td><td>$49</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: geomailapp.com">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://geospac.es">geospac.es</a></td><td>es</td><td>Internet</td><td>$499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: geospac.es">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://cycling.io">cycling.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Sports</td><td>$999</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: cycling.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://sociables.io">sociables.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Shopping</td><td>$1499</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: sociables.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://breakups.io">breakups.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Social</td><td>$799</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: breakups.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://meetingplanner.io">meetingplanner.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Internet</td><td>$1999</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: meetingplanner.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://starwars.io">starwars.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Entertainment</td><td>$799</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: starwars.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://acupuncture.io">acupuncture.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Healthcare</td><td>$599</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: acupuncture.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://gardening.io">gardening.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Gardening</td><td>$699</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: gardening.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://marriage.io">marriage.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Social</td><td>$599</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: marriage.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://startrek.io">startrek.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Entertainment</td><td>$399</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: startrek.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://thaimassage.io">thaimassage.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Healthcare</td><td>$449</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: thaimassage.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://acro.io">acro.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Yoga</td><td>$349</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: acro.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://acroyoga.io">acroyoga.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Yoga</td><td>$399</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: acroyoga.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://easylist.io">easylist.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Technology</td><td>$299</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: easylist.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://favorites.io">favorites.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Internet</td><td>$299</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: favorites.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://healing.io">healing.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Healthcare</td><td>$249</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: healing.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://snowboarder.io">snowboarder.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Sports</td><td>$349</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: snowboarder.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://snowboarding.io">snowboarding.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Sports</td><td>$399</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: snowboarding.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://fwb.io">fwb.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Social</td><td>$249</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: fwb.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://herbs.io">herbs.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Healthcare</td><td>$199</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: herbs.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://maryjane.io">maryjane.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Healthcare</td><td>$249</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: maryjane.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://outlets.io">outlets.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Shopping</td><td>$199</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: outlets.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://cloudmail.io">cloudmail.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Internet</td><td>$199</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: cloudmail.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://swingers.io">swingers.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Social</td><td>$149</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: swingers.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://imadethis.io">imadethis.io</a></td><td>io</td><td>Internet</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: imadethis.io">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://skymail.me">skymail.me</a></td><td>me</td><td>Internet</td><td>$69</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: skymail.me">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://tenideas.net">tenideas.net</a></td><td>net</td><td>Internet</td><td>$249</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: tenideas.net">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://activist.ninja">activist.ninja</a></td><td>ninja</td><td>Activism</td><td>$399</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: activist.ninja">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://federal.ninja">federal.ninja</a></td><td>ninja</td><td>Politics</td><td>$299</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: federal.ninja">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://newscloud.org">newscloud.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>News</td><td>$599</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: newscloud.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://communitystarter.org">communitystarter.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Internet</td><td>$399</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: communitystarter.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://tenideas.org">tenideas.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Internet</td><td>$349</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: tenideas.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://whistlerplaces.org">whistlerplaces.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Travel</td><td>$299</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: whistlerplaces.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://commonbits.org">commonbits.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Technology</td><td>$299</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: commonbits.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://commonroad.org">commonroad.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Internet</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: commonroad.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://commontunes.org">commontunes.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Music</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: commontunes.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://parentbuzz.org">parentbuzz.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Social</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: parentbuzz.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://sharecast.org">sharecast.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Internet</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: sharecast.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://socialscore.org">socialscore.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Internet</td><td>$99</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: socialscore.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://commonfilms.org">commonfilms.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Entertainment</td><td>$69</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: commonfilms.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://commonmedia.org">commonmedia.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Entertainment</td><td>$69</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: commonmedia.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://commonprose.org">commonprose.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Internet</td><td>$69</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: commonprose.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://geoclouds.org">geoclouds.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Internet</td><td>$69</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: geoclouds.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://identitycircle.org">identitycircle.org</a></td><td>org</td><td>Internet</td><td>$49</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: identitycircle.org">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://tenideas.us">tenideas.us</a></td><td>us</td><td>Activism</td><td>$599</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: tenideas.us">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://majorhomes.us">majorhomes.us</a></td><td>us</td><td>Shopping</td><td>$299</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: majorhomes.us">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://peoplefirst.us">peoplefirst.us</a></td><td>us</td><td>Activism</td><td>$199</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: peoplefirst.us">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://geogram.us">geogram.us</a></td><td>us</td><td>Internet</td><td>$49</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: geogram.us">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://idealog.us">idealog.us</a></td><td>us</td><td>Misc</td><td>$49</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: idealog.us">Purchase</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="http://newsi.us">newsi.us</a></td><td>us</td><td>News</td><td>$49</td><td><a href="mailto:jeff@lookahead.io?subject=Offer for domain name: newsi.us">Purchase</a></td></tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="pager" class="pager">
    <form>
        <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first"/>
        <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev"/>
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
        <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next"/>
        <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last"/>
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option  value="40">40</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#domainsTable").tablesorter({sortList: [[3,1],[2,0]]});
            }
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorting is working but bottom buttons looks like this
[image]
and doesn't work(is not clickable components).

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it looks like you're using tablesorter v2.0.5 (the original), but using the some pager HTML from my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/); it's not that much different.

Anyway, what's missing is the call to the tablesorter pager addon; it's under "Example 2" of the tutsplus article you posted:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("table")
        .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
        .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
});
</script>
```